# How many words with $r$ letters can be made out of $n$ letters?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

We have a set of $n$ letters that can be arranged in a word that fits $r$ letters, with $r\geq n$. It doesn't matter the order of the letters in the word.

How many words can be done?

> **A brief example**: Suppose we have the letters $A$ and $B$ ($n=2$) and the word has lenght of 2 letters ($r=2$). We can arrange that as $AA$, $BA$, $AB$ and $BB$. As the order does not matter the answer is $3$, because the sencond and the third form are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_two_2) problem.

We have $n$ frequency bins representing how many of each letter type is being used, and $r$ letters to allocate among those bins. There are

$$W = \binom{r+n-1}{n-1}$$

possible words.